# How to style parts of i18n messages when using thymeleaf

Tags: properties, localization, internationalization, thymeleaf

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this. I would like to know how best to style parts of messages from l10n properties files. For example, my client want this message and formatting in a help window:

> This is a **self-assessment** and **comparison** application.

Simplest solution would be to include the HTML tags in the messages.properties entry for this label. The problem with that is that the 40 translators that will process the messages.properties are bound to make mistakes like deleting the <, translating the attributes or styles of the HTML markup etc. Also it makes maintaining the markup and styling difficult for the devs.

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've seen typically done just uses `th:utext` with HTML tags in the .properties files.  I would opine it does create a maintenance hassle as you mention and should be kept to a minimum.

One workaround is to create separate strings in some cases, like:

```
<span th:text=#{thisIsA}>This is a </span><strong><span th:text="#{selfAssessment}">self-assessment</span></strong>
```

However, this is error-prone since certain languages may change the order of the words.  So that's not a great option.

If the HTML tags specifically are an issue, another way albeit somewhat ugly could be:

```
thisIsASelfAssessment=This is a {0}self-assessment{1}.
```

Or even

```
thisIsA=This is a {0}.
selfAssessment=self-assessment
```

But that might be confusing for the next developer reading it and may introduce the same issue you have with the 40 translators looking at it since you have curly braces.  It also all becomes very tedious and generates more lines.

So in the end, you're likely best going with the simplest solution of `utext`.

Project-wise, you could have the initial translation done without the markup and add the markup in after they are done with a first pass at translating it.  The issue may arise in the future when you need to change strings, but doing this would minimize some headache.  It could make sense to keep these strings in a separate block in the .properties file so you can target them later.

Good question as I've had this issue myself.

Comment: Keeping the translation without markup won't work, I won't know where to put the markup in a Chinese text for example. I could add some automated test to quickly spot where the syntax of the text is invalid and use the curly brace approach from you 2nd suggestion

Comment: Yes, you may even be able to use Thymeleaf to process the property values for syntax.  If you catch an exception, you know you've hit an issue.